# Get session variable using session uuid

Tags: lua, freeswitch

How am i able to get session variable using just session uuid (using lua).

So for example, we have session of leg_a (when someone connect sip phone). When other side answers, we will be within other session (session of leg_b).

Using just,

```
session:getVariable("variable_name")
```

will not help in that case because session refers to the current session.

How am i able to use lua to get variable name when i know session uuid. (so i can get other sessions variable, even we are within current session which is different)

Is there some kind of function where I am able to provide two parameteres, variable name and session uuid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to execute the API call `uuid_getvar`.

```
value = api:execute("uuid_getvar", "UUID VARNAME");
```

(I forgot how to concatenate strings in Lua, but you should get the idea)

Comment: ah yes, `uuid.."myvariable"`

Comment: additionaly, how its possible to set variable for that session so i can reuse it within another file....

api:execute("uuid_getvar", "UUID VARNAME VALUE"); seems to be not working. Am i missing something?

Comment: `uuid_setvar`  :-)   See also my Perl code in https://jira.freeswitch.org/browse/FS-6746

Comment: in comment above i was refering to the "uuid_setvar" just accidently copied part with getvar parameter.. anyway, i was able to make it work yesterday...

Comment: well, it worked for me (I'm using Perl, but it's talking to the same FreeSWITCH API). If you set and get a variable from two different scripts, you need to make sure that they are synchronized in time, and you read the variable after it's set.