# Setting/getting session variable in Load Impact (stress test tool) to perform stress test

Tags: lua, session-variables, uuid, stress-testing

I am currently looking for a way to get/set session variable in load impact. I tried to look for info via Google, but there isn't much info available. I tried this method from [Get session variable using session uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605796/get-session-variable-using-session-uuid)

```
value = api:execute("uuid_getvar", "UUID VARNAME");
```

but I received error saying "attempt to index global 'api' (a nil value)". Did I miss out certain steps? Or is this the appropriate way of getting session variable using load impact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean getting and setting a session variable in our service www.loadimpact.com that's not really applicable.

Then it depends on how you expose your session. If it's by cookies it's automatically handled.

It it's by session variables POSTed you will have to do some correlation in your script. Mainly by manual regex. Read up on an example at http://support.loadimpact.com/knowledgebase/articles/174607-testing-a-site-with-csrf-token-or-viewstate